# Missing right parenthesis in a Create sentence

Tags: sql, oracle

I get this missing right parenthesis but I cant find it

```
CREATE TABLE PUBLICACION AS 
(SELECT id AS id_revista,
 nombre AS nombre_revista, 
 COUNT(C.dni) AS cuantos_contratados, 
 COUNT(A.dni) AS cuantos_freelance
 FROM REVISTA, 
 PERIODISTA_CONTRATADO AS C, 
 PERIODISTA_FREELANCE AS A );
```

Comment: If you replace `PERIODISTA_CONTRATADO AS C, PERIODISTA_FREELANCE AS A` with `PERIODISTA_CONTRATADO C, PERIODISTA_FREELANCE A` does it work? I don't think you can use `AS` for table aliases in Oracle.

Comment: It does but now says column ambiguously defined.

Comment: You can fix that by specifying what table the columns come from. e.g. Likely you want to change `id AS id_revista, nombre AS nombre_revista` to `REVISTA.id AS id_revista, REVISTA.nombre AS nombre_revista`

Comment: Also, you should learn to write ANSI join syntax. The syntax you are using was deprecated over 30 years ago as ANSI join syntax is much easier to understand, maintain and debug

Comment: Yes, I know this is very outdated but I'm obligated to use it as my degree decided that this is the way to learn it so...

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, table aliases don't accept the `AS` keyword. You commented that - when you fixed that - you got the *column ambiguously defined* error. Must be one, or both, columns i SELECT that don't have table aliases and column(s) with the same name exist in two or all three tables. So, use table alias

What *is* missing, is the `group by` clause as all non-aggregated columns must be specified in that clause.

Therefore:

```
SQL> create table publicacion as
  2    select r.id           as id_revista,
  3           r.nombre       as nombre_revista,
  4           count(c.dni) as cuantos_contratados,
  5           count(a.dni) as cuantos_freelance
  6    from revista r,
  7         periodista_contratado c,
  8         periodista_freelance a
  9    group by id, nombre;

Table created.

SQL>
```

**However**, that's most probably wrong because you produced cross-join of all 3 tables from the `FROM` clause. As you decided to separate tables with commas, you'd now have to join tables in the `WHERE` clause, but that's not a good idea - explicitly `JOIN` tables, and leave the `WHERE` clause for possible conditions.

Comment: Why "I doubt it, at least not with code you posted as there are no duplicate column names there"? `id` and `nombre` could exist in more than one of those tables. If, for example,`id` exists in `revisita` and `periodista_contratado` I think a "column ambiguously defined" error is exactly what one would expect.